# Delay between sending and recieving SNMP Traps within a machine

Tags: snmpd, net-snmp, snmp

I am experimenting with sending and receiving SNMP traps via net-SNMP.  I have a script that sends traps out to localhost.  I have snmptrapd set to write traps to a file.  This works fine, except for the fact that there is about a 5 second delay between the trap getting sent and receiving the trap.  It is all on the same computer (snmptrapd is running on localhost), so why would there be such a large delay?  Also, when I send a large amount of traps at once, like 100 within 5 seconds, it will not write more than 1 every ~5 seconds.
Thanks!

Comment: `tcpdump` is your friend.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of rate limiting. Check your SNMP configs, firewall, and `tcpdump`.

Comment: There is nothing in the configs and the firewall is off.  I can't directly tell what is wrong with tcpdump.  I even tried using 2 virtual machines as opposed to one, one for sending and the other for receiving traps.  Needless to say there is still a delay.  The receiving server gets packets immediately after the trap is sent, and then gets packets about 5 seconds later, which is when the trap is actually received.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the exact same issue. Still haven't found any answer but I will keep digging and post back if I do.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was DNS look ups timing out so I just pushed the `-n` flag to the options lines in `/etc/defaults/snmpd`. This was on Debian 6.0.

> # snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).
>       SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /var/log/snmpd.log **-n** -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'
>
> # snmptrapd options (use syslog).
>       TRAPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /var/log/snmptrapd.log **-n** -u snmp -g snmp -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid'

This was for:
 NET-SNMP Version:  5.4.3
on a Debian 6.0 server, the behaviour seems to have changed since Debian 5.0.